# Limitations with Java Hotswap

Tags: java, debugging, hotswap

The java [hotswap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping) feature save a lot of time for me. However, it has many limitations (like schema change is not supported). Any idea if the limitation is going to be addressed any sooner? According to this [forum entry](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=3949087), it seems to be ignored.

I know that products like JRebel helps. But does anyone know about any open source tools for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [Dynamic Code Evolution VM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) (also at http://java.net/projects/dcevm)

Answer (score 1):

JavaRebel is a good tool, but it need you purchase.

I'd like advice to you use hotswaping ant tool:

http://www.asjava.com/core-java/how-to-hotswap-java-code-into-jvm-redefinition-example/

Answer (score 0):

OSGI is supposed to have come some way on this problem. You may want to have a look at [apache felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [Eclipse Equinox](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/).